# Calculation of blood flow rate and pressure change in heart

Tags: homework, cardiology, blood-pressure

Question: Blood flows from the left ventricle of the heart through the aortic valve and then to the aorta for system circulation. In a patient, the diameter of left ventricle outflow tract (LVOT) is found to be 1.6 cm, the aortic valve 8.0 mm and the aorta was 2.0 cm. Vitals of the patient indicate a 5.0 L/min cardiac output, a heart rate of 70 beats per minute and a duration of the ejection phase during each beat of 300 ms.

1. What is the volumetric flow rate during the ejection phase of the beat?
2. What is the pressure change over the valve?

You can assume the density of blood to be 1.06 g/cm3.
(answers: $Q$ = 0.24 L/s, $Δp31$ = -440 Pa)

For the first question, I tried to use the formula:

$Q = AV$

Where $Q$ = Flow rate, $A$ = cross-sectional area, and $V$ = velocity.

I calculated $A$ for LVOT, valve, aorta with $\pi r^2$, and calculated $V$ by dividing the diameter with 300 ms, and calculated $Q$ (with unit of L/s) by $AV$. Then I calculated the volumetric flow by adding each flow rate, but the result wasn't 0.24 L/s. I guess my approach is mistake, but I don't know how to solve it then.

For the second question, with bernoulli's equation, I tried to calculate the pressure change by $(0.5)*density*((V $of lvot$)^2-(V $of aorta$)^2)$, but the result wasn't -440 Pa. What are other things I should consider?

Comment: Is this possibly better suited for [medical sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/)? The question can be migrated if you want.

Comment: It's more of just a physics question; no biology or medicine is needed to answer.